# Android contacts app that properly handles vCard UIDs to prevent duplicates

Tags: android, contact-manager, file-format, vcard

I am looking for a contacts management application for my Android 8 phone. Requirements:

- The app must be able to export all contacts into a vCard 3.0 or vCard 4.0 file on my phone's internal storage.
- During export into a vCard file, it should produce vCard UIDs for contacts that have no existing UID.
- During import of vCard files, it should properly handle UIDs to prevent duplicate contacts.
- If a contact that is being imported has the same UID as an existing contact on the phone, the app should prompt the user to determine how to merge the two contacts. This is important for data correctness.
- The app should preferably be free and open source.

I have already tried [Simple Contacts Pro](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.simplemobiletools.contacts.pro/). Although it is able to export contacts into vCard 4.0 format, the contacts that it exports have no UID. This would cause duplicate entries when I periodically import the vCard file into a contacts manager on my desktop computer.